# LINQ to XML : Sequence contains no elements

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

I have this XML

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <root>
        <xsd:schema id="root" xmlns="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
        <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" />
        <xsd:element name="root" msdata:IsDataSet="true">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:element name="metadata">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute ref="xml:space" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="assembly">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:attribute name="alias" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="data">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
                <xsd:element name="comment" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
              <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="3" />
              <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="4" />
              <xsd:attribute ref="xml:space" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="resheader">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
        </xsd:choice>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
   </xsd:schema>
  <resheader name="resmimetype">
    <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="version">
    <value>2.0</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="reader">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="writer">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
  <data name="Nieuws" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>News</value>
  </data>
  <data name="Pagina's" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Pages</value>
  </data>
  <data name="searchreasults" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>There were no matches found</value>
  </data>
</root>
```

And I also have this method, where I take two files and take some values from them, and then I merge all the values into an object in the second query:

```
Public Shared Function RetrieveTranslation(ByVal filefrom As String, ByVal fileto As String) As List(Of clsTranslation)
    Dim valuefrom = (From l In XElement.Load(fileto).Elements("data") Select l.Element("value").Value).FirstOrDefault

    Dim valuetrans = From vl In XElement.Load(filefrom).Elements("data") Select (New clsTranslation With {.Filename = filefrom, .Value = vl.Element("value").Value, .Valueto = valuefrom.ToString, .TranslationId = vl.Attribute("name").Value})
    Return valuetrans.ToList

End Function
```

So, the problem is that when I run the code, there is an "Sequence contains no elements" error in the first query(valuefrom). I debugged and it says that there is nothing in the query, but I don't understand why, 'cos I did similar things and never had a problem like this one.

Any hints?

Thanks in advance,

Alf.

P.S: Oh! And by the way, I'm curious to know if it is well done to do something like I did, create an object from two queries, putting the first value in the second query. Thanks!

Comment: Well you have posted a small snippet of markup that is not even a well-formed XML document. I suspect the problem is related to namespaces declared in parts of the document you have not shown. Either show us any namespace declarations in ancestor elements of those "data" elements or try whether you can figure it out yourself with the help of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387093.aspx.

Comment: hmmm... I'll check the page. I also update with the whole XML Document,though the part I posted is the most important

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with your sample XML, I saved your complete XML sample as "XMLFile1.xml" and then simply executed two lines of code `Dim valuefrom = (From l In XElement.Load("..\..\XMLFile1.xml").Elements("data") Select l.Element("value").Value).FirstOrDefault` and `Console.WriteLine(valuefrom)` and I don't get any error, rather "News" is output. So somehow your actual code producing that error must be different.

Comment: Yes, actually I'm getting this error using First instead FirstOrDefault. But using the last one, I get another error. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."... It seems it cannot create the object, but why?

Comment: It seems that the value is null, but actually you could take a value with Console.Writeline(valuefrom)... this is what I do not understand...

Comment: SOLVED! My problem was not with the code, but with other XML files that were empty... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! My problem was not with the code, but with other XML files that were empty... Thanks for the help!